# Redis latency measurement using php script

Tags: php, redis, latency, predis

Pardon me for asking this basic question.

I have installed redis and predis (client library) on my local ubuntu machine. Now, I am doing certain SET/GET operations in my php script. I just want to know how may I "exactly calculate" the time redis server took to complete the "SET" or "GET" operation.
redis-cli --latency gives you an average, but actually does not list the individual time taken for any operation.

My objective is to execute around 100 such instructions and find out the average time taken for execution per instruction.

Any suggestion is highly welcome.

Here's my php client script:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
require __DIR__.'/predis/src/Autoloader.php';
Predis\Autoloader::register();
// since we connect to default setting localhost
// and 6379 port there is no need for extra
// configuration. If not then you can specify the
// scheme, host and port to connect as an array
// to the constructor.
try {
$redis = new Predis\Client();
//$redis = new PredisClient();
/*
$redis = new PredisClient(array(
"scheme" => "tcp",
"host" => "127.0.0.1",
"port" => 6379));
*/

echo "<br />Successfully connected to Redis<br />";
//$redis->set("hello_world", "Hi from php!");
//$value = $redis->get("hello_world");

$sum = 0;
$time_start = microtime(true);
echo "<br />Start Time: $time_start";
$c = $redis->hset("taxi_car1", "brand", "Toyota");
$time_stop = microtime(true);

echo "<br /> Time taken for this instruction:".($time_stop-$time_start)*1000;
$sum += ($time_stop-$time_start)*1000;

$time_start = microtime(true);
$redis->hset("taxi_car1", "model", "Corolla");
$time_stop = microtime(true);
echo "<br /> Time taken for this instruction:".($time_stop-$time_start)*1000;
$sum += ($time_stop-$time_start)*1000;

echo "<br />Stop Time: $time_stop<br />";
echo "Average Time Taken: ".($sum/2);

//var_dump($value);
//echo "<br />$value<br />"; 
echo ($redis->exists("Santa Claus")) ? "true" : "false";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Couldn't connected to Redis";
}
?>
```

I know this is is not a correct way. would be nice if somebody can suggest a proper way to calculate this average latency. I ultimately plan to extend this to a distributed system.

### Thanks in advance.

Update:

I tried enabling slow logs to see the execution time of a particular command. However, when the set of commands are a little bigger (say 100), then to calculate avg. execution time manually, becomes a tedious task. I am looking forward to doing it through a php script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [INFO commandstats](http://redis.io/commands/info). If you want to reset the stats, run [CONFIG RESETSTAT](http://redis.io/commands/config-resetstat).

Comment: I tried enabling slow logs to see exactly how much time is taken to execute GET/SET commands. But my objective here is to get the same stuff done through a php script. Just wished to know if there exists some method that would do this? This is because for 100 instructions, it's tedious to look into slow logs manually, to calculate the average execution time.